# JavaScript's DateTime processing and it's inconsistencies compared to other languages

Tags: javascript, objective-c

I'm just wondering what happens when passing an invalid Date into JavaScripts Date Object and the passed date was invalid.

e.g. 2015-11-31 (Not valid because November only has 30 Days)

Here an example:

```
new Date("2015-11-31T23:59:59.999Z").toISOString() 
//Results in 2015-12-01T23:59:59.999Z
```

Ok the date seems to be interpolated and a comparison in a different language (Objective C) is particular similar.

But when I try the following example:

```
new Date("2015-11-32T23:59:59.999Z").toISOString() 
// It results with an Error
Uncaught RangeError: Invalid time value
```

And compared to Objective C it's now different because Objective C results with

```
2015-12-02T23:59:59.999Z
```

What's the reason for this behavior and which one is more "correct"?

Comment: i imagine it is wrong because no valid date can have a day of >31 days

Comment: Hey  @Beast-a-tron That's true... But it's even possible in ObjectiveC with a suitable result...

Comment: They are different languages, I guess they handle it in different ways. FWIW, JavaScript will happily cast ' new Date(2015,11,32) ' into the right format. So Date.parse() must be unable to read the string (likely due to the 32 being present)

Comment: @Beast-a-tron new Date(2015,11,32.toISOString() results in a completely strange result ("2015-12-31T23:00:00.000Z")

Comment: That looks like it has daylight savings time issues with it. And don't forget that the 11 going into the Date is December (due to 0 being Jan), and thus is the same as the 12 which comes out in the string. Apart from that hour, it looks correct (would be 2016-01-01, which is 32 days after 1st Dec)